# Spark 2.0 filter using a UDF after a self-join

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to filter a Spark dataframe using my own User-Defined Function. My dataframe is read from a database using a jdbc connection and then goes through a self-join operation in spark before being filtered. The error occurs when trying to `collect` the dataframe after the filter.

I have been using this successfully in spark 1.6. However, after upgrading to 2.0 yesterday it fails with the error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o400.collectToPython.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: 
<lambda>(input[0, string, true])
```

Here is a minimal example that produces the error (in my environment):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('test').getOrCreate()

# this works successfully
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Alice', 1), ('Bob', 2), ('Dan', None)], 
                           ['name', 'age'])
df.filter(udf(lambda x: 'i' in x, BooleanType())(df.name)).collect()
>>> [Row(name=u'Alice', age=1)]

# this produces the error
df_emp = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'Alice', None), (2, 'Bob', 1), 
                                (3, 'Dan', 2), (4, 'Joe', 2)], 
                               ['id', 'name', 'manager_id'])
df1 = df_emp.alias('df1')
df2 = df_emp.alias('df2')
cols = df1.columns
# the self-join
result = df1.join(df2, col('df1.id') == col('df2.manager_id'), 'left_outer')
result.collect()
>>> [Row(id=1, name=u'Alice', manager_id=None), 
     Row(id=3, name=u'Dan', manager_id=2), Row(id=2, name=u'Bob', manager_id=1), 
     Row(id=2, name=u'Bob', manager_id=1), Row(id=4, name=u'Joe', manager_id=2)]

# simple udf filter
filtered = result.filter(udf(lambda x: 'i' in x, BooleanType())(result.name))
filtered.collect()
# the above error is produced...
```

Am I doing anything wrong in this case? Is this a bug in 2.0 or should I consider some change in behavior between the two versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in pyspark.

I have filed a bug for it here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17100

This problem arises in left_outer, right_outer and outer joins, but not for inner joins.

One workaround is to cache the join result before the filter.

eg:

`result = df1.join(df2, col('df1.id') == col('df2.manager_id'), 
                  'left_outer').select(df2.name).cache()`

Comment: i was banging my head on the wall because a udf that worked in a previous session was failing. this saved me! thanks Tim!